# How to Union Intersecting Geometries in Same Geopandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, union, intersect, geopandas

I have a dataframe with circles, some of which intersect others. I want to merge those intersecting regions to be new rows in the dataframe, adding the attributes from the intersecting regions. I only see how to use sjoin between two dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
import geopandas as gpd, pandas as pd
from urbansim.maps import dframe_explorer
from shapely.geometry import Point
%matplotlib inline

c1 = Point(1, 0).buffer(1)
c2 = Point(.5, 0).buffer(1)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict(A=[1, 2], B=[3, 4]), geometry=[c1, c2])

gdf.plot()
```

[image]

**Solution**
Using `reduce` from `functools`

```
from functools import reduce

intersection = reduce(Point.intersection, gdf.geometry) 

summed = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gdf.sum().to_frame().T,
    geometry=[intersection]
)

gdf.set_geometry(
    gdf.difference(intersection)
).append(summed, ignore_index=True).plot()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. this is a helpful part of the answer, but then the gdf will have the original polygons and their intersections. I want to split them up. So I want the intersection and then the parts that don't intersect. Relating it to the plots above, I want the right-facing crescent, the intersection, and the left-facing crescent. Pardon any ambiguity in my original question

Comment: You're welcome... just to let you know, you accepting this answer is what just put me over 90,000 rep.  Thanks!

Comment: I am honored, and I am sure you very much deserve it!

Comment: hey, so I just got back to working on this and I now see that this finds a single intersection, no matter how many disjoint sets of intersecting polygons. Can't think of a reasonable way to do this (I could iterate through table starting with pairs, then triplets, etc to find all possible intersections, but that is wildly expensive). Basically I want it to be like arcmap's union as shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/XOI9k) but within one table